# Image does not render in browser when hosted on the hard drive: I.E. Firefox, Safari, loads in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, firefox, safari

My app is supposed to draw a grid over an image and provide you with the coordinates of that grid.  This however does not seem to work in I.E., Safari, and Firefox when the image is hosted on my local machine.  When I host the photo on Picasa the images show up fine.  This is working in Chrome. The images will eventually be hosted on my server but I am working with it locally first.  I am really new to this.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you

Here is the HTML and javascript I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.0/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Grid test</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css\grid_style.css">
  <img src="c:\EA_A02_N_1-4_5mM_Xgal_7d_B.cropped.resized.grey.png" id="img"/>
  <script>
  function SetGrid(el) {
  var size = el.getSize();
  var coord = el.getCoordinates();
  var gridTable = new Element('table', {
    'id' : 'gridTable',
    'styles' : {
      'position': 'absolute',
        'width' : size.x,
        'height' : size.y,
        'top' : coord.top,
        'left' : coord.left
    }
  });

  var numcols = 48;
  var numrows = 32;
  var cellSize = {
    width: size.x / numcols,
    height: size.y / numrows
  }

  for (var row = 1; row<=numrows; row++){
      thisRow = new Element('tr', {
          'id' : row,
          'class' : 'gridRow'
      });
      for(var col = 1; col<=numcols; col++){
          thisCol = new Element('td', {
              'id' : col,
              'title': row + ' x ' + col,
              'class' : 'gridCol0'
          });
          thisCol.inject(thisRow, 'bottom');
      };
      thisRow.inject(gridTable, 'bottom');
  }

  gridTable.addEvents({
    // Add the click event to the gridTable
    click: function(e) {
      // Do something with the grid position.
      alert(Math.floor((e.client.x - coord.left) / cellSize.width) 
            + ', ' + Math.floor((e.client.y - coord.top)/ cellSize.height));
    }
  });

  gridTable.inject(el.getParent());
}


window.addEvent('load', function() {
    SetGrid($('img'));
  }
);</script>

</body>
</html>​
```

Comment: I'm not having any trouble with this either in Windows or Linux. I had to change the image file name to test it. Maybe you have a file name typo? OR are you running the page from a web server and asking for the image from a file?

Comment: @Hemlock I double checked the name it looks fine, it also works for me in Chrome, it still not loading in FireFox or Safari though. Right now I am running everything from my local machine before moving it over to the server.

Comment: Are you running a local web server? If not, you probably should. It will make your life easier in the long run since your development and production environments will be similar (you won't have to change paths to files, for instance). Check out XAMPP if you don't want to use IIS or keep a server running all the time http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html.

Comment: @Hemlock  I am just running it on my local machine right now, so I think you and @awoodland are right I suspect that I have something wrong with the settings on my machine or something to that affect.  I will move it over to an actual web server (non production).  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a security "zone" related problem. Browsers tend to be picky about allowing javascript from external URLs run alongside code that reads things off the local disk for fear of leaking confidential information.

Does it work if you host all the javascript locally too?

Comment: You mean just grab a local version of mootools too?  I have not tried that, but will give it a shot.

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. I seem to recall some further restrictions with local javascript and local files though. It might be easier just to install apache or IIS on your test box to avoid these kinds of problems which won't exist when you deploy it.

Comment: I just changed it so that both mootools-yui-compressed.js and html5.js are stored locally and I there is no change.